# Forgetting free category, same-same but different?

Tags: category-theory

I know almost nothing about categories but I was reading about the [universal property of free categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_category#Universal_property). If C(G) is the free category generated by the graph $G$ and U is the forgetful functor, what is the difference between the graph $G$ and $U(C(G))$? What would be an instance where they are different? For example if I take a graph $G$ as $a\overset{f}{\underset{g}{\leftrightarrows}}b\overset{h}{\rightarrow} c$ the arrows of $C(G)$ are the three identity arrows and $f, g, h, f\circ g\, g\circ f, h, h\circ g, f\circ g\circ f, g\circ f\circ g, ...$ and $U(C(G))$ would be the same as $G$ no?

Comment: You listed more than 3 arrows for $C(G)$. Each of them will become an edge in $U(C(G))$, so it has more edges than $G$. (Also don't forget the identity arrows.)

Comment: @N.Virgo I see so basically there will be infinitely many arrows between $a$ and $b$ in $U(C(G))$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Infinitely many from $a$ to $b$, $b$ to $a$, $a$ to itself and $b$ to itself. Also infinitely many from $a$ and $b$ to $c$, coming from morphisms like $h\circ g\circ f \circ g$. But only one edge from $c$ to itself.

Comment: Thank you for the useful comment, it helped me understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying category of a free category has freely added compositions.

For example the free category on the graph $G=x \rightarrow y \rightarrow z$ will have a composite arrow $x\rightarrow z$, i.e. we have
$$UC(G) = \begin{array}{ccc}
x &\rightarrow&y\\
&\searrow&\downarrow\\
&&z
\end{array}.$$

If you call this new graph above $G'$ and consider $UC(G')$, what will happen? By applying $U$ you forgot about compositions, so the diagonal arrow $x\rightarrow z$ is not to be regarded as the composite $x \rightarrow y \rightarrow z$. Thus $UC(G')$ has a newly added composite and may be depicted as
$$UC(G') = \begin{array}{ccc}
x &\rightarrow&y\\
&\searrow\searrow&\downarrow\\
&&z
\end{array}.$$

Even worse, if you have a finite graph $G$ with a nontrivial cycle, then the graph $UC(G)$ will have infinitely many arrows. Take for example $G=\underset{\circlearrowright f}x$, then you will get a graph $UC(G)$ with infinitely many cylces, one for each $n$-fold composite $f^{n} = f\circ ... \circ f$.

So in fact it is rarely the case, that $UC(G) \cong G$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the difference now. On another note, I don't quite understand what "**freely** added composition" means? How to interpret this word "freely" in this context. I remember reading the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_category) article they use the same terminology of "freely concatenating arrows together". This is more of a language issue but what is the difference between "concatenating arrows together" and "freely concatenating arrows together"?

Comment: free is meant in the sense "we are so free to ignore existing relations / compositions and add our own". Also, feel free to accept the answer to remove the question from the *unanswered questions* heap...